# Permissions Error using Jupyter magic command %load_ext google.cloud.bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook

Apologies for the complexity of this question, and I really appreciate any help. I'm currently trying to follow the Google tutorial to visualize BigQuery data in a Jupyter notebook (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-jupyter). I have permission to use Project-1, but not Project-2.

When I execute the first 2 commands:

```
%load_ext google.cloud.bigquery
```

```
%%bigquery
SELECT
    source_year AS year,
    COUNT(is_male) AS birth_count
FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.natality`
GROUP BY year
ORDER BY year DESC
LIMIT 15
```

...I get an error in the following format:

```
Caller does not have required permission to use project Project-2
```

However, when I run `!gcloud config list` in the notebook, it lists the following (along w/ the correct email account)

```
[accessibility]
screen_reader = true
[core]
disable_usage_reporting = True
project = Project-1

Your active configuration is: [default]
```

Am I incorrectly understanding how the `%load_ext google.cloud.bigquery` statement works? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to [project selector page](https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector2/home/dashboard?_ga=2.238646464.1737290243.1582533511-1692182101.1565005320&_gac=1.79731173.1581922591.Cj0KCQiA7aPyBRChARIsAJfWCgJ02G0oi9D-f8S4vqIprLrLBBbcKLZXoZRcsS4nKvXtViIcMRMjFG4aAl35EALw_wcB) and select project `Project-2`, and run `gcloud config set project Project-2` command in a cloud shell. Than, check in `API & Services -> Credentials` section, if you have created any credentials, which allows you to access your enabled APIs, look [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started).

You can also execute `gcloud auth login` to specify the credentials that you want to use. Use the same ones that you login to the Google Cloud Console.

The BigQuery Python client library support querying data stored in BigQuery. `%load_ext google.cloud.bigquery` is one of the many Jupyter built-in commands, which loads the commands from the client library.

Let me know about the results. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Hey, really appreciate the response! The command that ended up solving the issue was gcloud auth application-default login